# HTML form do some "action" when hit submit button

Tags: html, form-submit

I would like to learn about HTML forms. For example, I have 2 input text fields for first name and last name and a submit button. When the submit button is clicked, I would like the webpage to display something like: Your Name is "First Name" "Last Name".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <form>
         First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
         Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form> 
   </body>
</html>
```

What do I need to have here in order to have some "action" when I click that button?

**Edit:** Ok now I figure out that I need either PHP or JavaScript here. Can some one suggest or provide a sample code of PHP or Js as a reference for me?

Comment: Your `<form>` should have an `action` and a `method` attribute

Comment: ok thanks I will do research about it.

Comment: Sure there must be a duplicate four years in?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok, I'll take a stab at this.  If you want to work with PHP, you will need to install and configure both PHP and a webserver on your machine.  This article might get you started: [PHP Manual: Installation on Windows systems](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php)

Once you have your environment setup, you can start working with webforms. Directly From the article: [Processing form data with PHP](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ss/php_forms.htm):

> For this example you will need to create two pages. On the first page
>   we will create a simple HTML form to collect some data. Here is an
>   example:
>
> ```
> <html>   
> <head>
>  <title>Test Page</title>
> </head>   
> <body>   
>     <h2>Data Collection</h2><p>
>     <form action="process.php" method="post">  
>         <table>
>             <tr>
>                 <td>Name:</td>
>                 <td><input type="text" name="Name"/></td>
>             </tr>   
>             <tr>
>                 <td>Age:</td>
>                 <td><input type="text" name="Age"/></td>
>             </tr>   
>             <tr>
>                 <td colspan="2" align="center">
>                 <input type="submit"/>
>                 </td>
>             </tr>
>         </table>
>     </form>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> This page will
>   send the Name and Age data to the page process.php.  Now lets create process.php to use 
>   the data from the HTML form we made:

```
<?php   
    print "Your name is ". $Name;   
    print "<br />";   
    print "You are ". $Age . " years old";   
    print "<br />";   $old = 25 + $Age;
    print "In 25 years you will be " . $old . " years old";   
?>
```

> As you
>   may be aware, if you leave out the method="post" part of the form, the
>   URL with show the data. For example if your name is Bill Jones and you
>   are 35 years old, our process.php page will display as
>   http://yoursite.com/process.php?Name=Bill+Jones&Age=35 If you want,
>   you can manually change the URL in this way and the output will change
>   accordingly.

**Additional JavaScript Example**

This single file example takes the html from your question and ties the onSubmit event of the form to a JavaScript function that pulls the values of the 2 textboxes and displays them in an alert box.

**Note**: `document.getElementById("fname").value` gets the object with the `ID` tag that equals `fname` and then pulls it's `value` - which in this case is the text in the First Name textbox.

```
 <html>
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function ExampleJS(){
        var jFirst = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        var jLast = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        alert("Your name is: " + jFirst + " " + jLast);
     }
     </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <FORM NAME="myform" onSubmit="JavaScript:ExampleJS()">

             First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" /><br />
             Last name:  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" /><br />
            <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Update" />
        </FORM>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you! Very nice explanation! I have a online host and web-server ready. I will read and try your help. Just need you check back here and help me more :)

Comment: I got idea with PHP, in this case I may want something simpler like just a HTML file only, so I know I have to have some sort of JavaScript function on <head> tag, can you help me out there?

Comment: Added a JS example at the end of my answer

Comment: Is there a reason for `<form>` in first example and `<FORM>` in the 2nd one?

Comment: For me, the PHP example only works by replacing `$Age` and `$Name` with `$_POST['Age']` and `$_POST['Name']`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
       <form action="submit.php" method="POST">
         First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br /><br />
         Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form> 
   </body>
</html>
```

After that one more file which page you want to display after pressing the  submit button

**submit.php**

```
<html>
  <body>

    Your First Name is -  <?php echo $_POST["firstname"]; ?><br>
    Your Last Name is -   <?php echo $_POST["lastname"]; ?>

  </body>
</html>
```