# How can I have a form field generate the current date and time and then send that information on submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, date

I've got a simple registration form, and when the form gets submitted I want to be able to see not just the registrants' basic details but also the date and/or time (at least the date) they registered. I've looked up so many tutorials where JavaScript generates it in the field and it does when I load the form (it's a regular html page, no CMS or database is involved) but after I submit and go to check the registrant details where we keep all the lists, that information isn't there.

Comment: in which field? show the code which you are trying.

Comment: Hi could not answer ur qs exactly but got something that will help u start..                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006443/html-form-do-some-action-when-hit-submit-button

Comment: @ nikspv - not trying anything at the moment, tried too many options :( i just want the date and time to be generated in a field of their own, doesn't matter what type, as long as that information is generated automatically, is hidden from the registrant, and then gets sent on with the rest of the details that have been filled into the form by a registrant.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript,

```
function generateDate(){
    var currentTime = new Date();                
    var curdate = currentTime.getDate();
    document.getElementbyId("dateHidden").value = curdate;
    return true;
}
```

Declare this in the form:
`<input type="hidden" name="Language" id="dateHidden">`

`<form name="myform" action="JavaScript:generateDate()">`

Hope this is what you need.

Comment: sorry, i'm very new at this - where exactly does this go and what should the details in the input field be?

Comment: do you want to show these values in the fields or do you want this to go along with other details when you submit the form?

Comment: create hidden field like this in the form. `<input type="hidden" name="Language" id="dateHidden">` then in javascript assign curdate to dateHidden.

Comment: for the result i want these details to be sent to the mailing list along with what has been put into the name, email address etc. fields. so i'm guessing that it would need to go along with the other details when i submit the form. but, ideally, i do not want the person to see that the date and time have been generated as it's unnecessary so it would be hidden from their view.

Comment: In that case please refer to my comment above

Comment: What is not generated?

Comment: i need the field to generate the current time and date once the form gets submitted. but that field stays blank.

Comment: I have edited my answer to match your requirements. please check

Comment: unfortunately that won't work as the action currently contains a URL generated by the email platform, to where everyting is validated :(

Comment: you could try onSubmit instead. how are you planning to submit the values then? Can I see your code please? It is very vague at the moment

Comment: sure:<form id="e2ma_signup" action="https://app.e2ma.net/app2/audience/signup/1747787/1724118/?v=a" onsubmit="return signupFormObj.checkForm(this)" method="post">
<form method="post" id="signup" name="signup">     
<input type="hidden" name="prev_member_email" id="id_prev_member_email"/>
<input type="hidden" name="source" id="id_source"/>                        
<input type="hidden" name="group_2725590" value="2725590" id="id_group_2725590"/>
<input type="hidden" name="prev_member_email" value=""/>

Comment: put generateDate() inside checkForm(xx), that will do the trick

Comment: is it ok to keep the current id of the field rather than using Language? it needs to correspond to a field created in the mailing list.

Comment: It is always better to use id as it is unique. Does the mailing list use ids or names? if you can use id, rename the id `dateHidden` to `Language`. That was just an example you can create a hidden field with whatever name and id you would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

Server side languages like PHP have built-in functions for Date and Time, That is more reliable as users may not have set proper time on their computers.

Please post your code, it will help us understand better

Comment: First name * <input type="text" field_id="262406" name="member_field_first_name" id="id_member_field_first_name" class="input" size="20"/>
Last name * <input type="text" field_id="263430" name="member_field_last_name" id="id_member_field_last_name" class="input" size="20"/>
Email *<input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="id_email" size="20"/>
<input id="date-of-registration1" name="date-of-registration1" class="input" />

<input type="image" src="reg.jpg" name="Submit" value="Subscribe" class="submit">

Answer (score 0):

```
        <Script>var currentTime = new Date();                
        var curdate = currentTime.getDate();
        document.getElementbyId("date-of-registration1").value = curdate;
        </script>
        <form>
First name * <input type="text" field_id="262406" name="member_field_first_name" id="id_member_field_first_name" class="input" size="20"/>
Last name * <input type="text" field_id="263430" name="member_field_last_name" id="id_member_field_last_name" class="input" size="20"/>
Email *<input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="id_email" size="20"/>
<input id="date-of-registration1" name="date-of-registration1" class="input" type=hidden/> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Subscribe" class="submit">
        </form>
```